# Simple Bootstrap Modal didn't work in HTML

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I want to add simple Bootstrap modal in this code, and it didn't work! I follow a tutorial and there it works. I added Bootstrap link in header section, and bundle script in body section and also for jQuery script in body section.

When I click on img which is key to open modal site goes very upside.

Here's the markup:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Cyber security</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
           <div class="pre-header">
             <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p>Under Attack?- S.O.S. line</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                        <ul class="secondary-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Presale Service</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">White Paper</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="main-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                       <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <ul class="main-manu">
                            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">RATING</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">JOB</a></li>
                            <li ><a class="main-cta-btn" href="#">FREE QUOTE</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
    
        <div class="hero-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>Cyber security is not optional</h1>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut eius dicta voluptate, in commodi voluptatibus porro laudantium optio illum accusantium consequatur asperiores nihil magnam impedit fuga quidem. Sint, fugit architecto.</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="main-cta-btn">Discover more</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="services-section">
            <h3>Our Services</h3>
            <h2>360° PROTECTION</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br/>Natus minus ducimus provident ipsam quae, maxime consequatur dolore, culpa quas adipisci<br/> consectetur asperiores! Vel corporis, nostrum alias cumque exercitationem quidem magnam?</p>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="images/col-1.jpg" alt="">
                        <h4>Threats block</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur </p>
                        <a href="#">Info and plans</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="images/col-2.jpg" alt="">
                    <h4>Threats block</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur </p>
                    <a href="#">Info and plans</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="images/col-3.jpg" alt="">
                    <h4>Threats block</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur </p>
                    <a href="#">Info and plans</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    
    
     <div class="how-it-works-section">
                    <h3>Experiance safety</h3>
                    <h2>HOW IT WORKS?</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br/>Natus minus ducimus provident ipsam quae, </p>
                    
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" href="#videoModal">
                    <img src="images/video-image.jpg" alt=""> 
                </a>   
                        
                    <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="videoModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed closing your `how-it-works-section` `</div>`

You also need to put the Bootstrap CDN for CSS inside your head tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

After adding the `link` tag to your `<head>` section, the modal currently technically lives inside inside that `how-it-works-section` DIV and won't work in most cases.

Should look like:

```
...
...

<div class="how-it-works-section">
    <h3>Experiance safety</h3>
    <h2>HOW IT WORKS?</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br/>Natus minus ducimus provident ipsam quae, </p>

    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" href="#videoModal">
        <img src="images/video-image.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="videoModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

...
...
```

**UPDATE**

I took for granted that you actually CALLED the modal .. You need to call it into existence ..  IE add this UNDER the `<script src` tags in your HTML (just above the `</body>` tag)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#videoModal").modal("show");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I put youre correcting code, and link in header and it didn't work either

Comment: I took for granted you were actually CALLING the modal ..  See **UPDATE** above

Comment: Yeah, now it works, but it opens when I refresh page but I want it to pop up when I click on image:

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" href="#videoModal">
        <img src="images/video-image.jpg" alt="">
    </a>

Comment: `<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">`

Comment: It doesn't work :( It shows again when I load page

Comment: Remove the script in the update ..   You need a tutorial on this .. This is basic functionality ..  You may be out of your depth until you read the [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)

Answer (score 0):

I need to do 3 things:

1. I need to call modal like this:

   $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#img").click(function () {
                   $('#videoModal').modal("show");
               });
               });

To call modal I needed to fix these lines:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal"  >
        <img id="img" src="images/video-image.jpg" alt="" > 
    </a>
```

And to work modal propertly i need to add bs inthere:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).